# type object 'Teachprofile' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Models.py

```
class Teachprofile:
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=51)
    DOB=models.DateField()
    Address=models.TextField()
    Place=models.CharField(max_length=51)
    City=models.CharField(max_length=51)
    State=models.CharField(max_length=51)
    course=models.ForeignKey(Courses,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
```

Forms.py

```
class Teachprofeditform(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Teachprofile 
        exclude = ['owner']
```

When I running the server,I get error as

```
File "D:\Newproject\elearn\views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .forms import UserRegistrationForm,CourseeditForm,ExameditForm,MarkeditForm,Teachprofeditform,Stuprofeditform
  File "D:\Newproject\elearn\forms.py", line 32, in <module>
    class Teachprofeditform(forms.ModelForm):
  File "D:\Newproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 306, in __new__
    fields = fields_for_model(
  File "D:\Newproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 181, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'Teachprofile' has no attribute '_meta'
```

I tried so many ways to debug,but didn't get the expected results.Also unable to migrate.I have to run the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit your class `Teachprofile` from Django's default model class

```
from django.db import models


class TeachProfile(models.Model):
```

NB: Keep your field name's in lower-case letters.

eg : dob, address, place, city etc